# arm navigation - problem with violating joint limits

Tags: ros, arm-navigation, joints

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am having a problem with the pr2 violating the joint limits that are set for it in arm_navigation. I have done a little research on it and it sounds like the joint limits are set to be very conservative, especially on the wrist flex joints. I'm sure that the joint limits are set somewhere in a yaml file, but where can I find them? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42261/arm-navigation---problem-with-violating-joint-limits/) by [jeffreyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3080/jeffreyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-08-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeffreyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3080/jeffreyk/) on 2012-08-26**:
thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The software joint limits are defined in the PR2's URDF files. You can read more on the limits [here](http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2%20Manual/Chapter8).

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1